# Get MVC to retrieve action result on server side without authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building an export feature on my Asp.net MVC site, which is a `FileResult` action that is harvesting the result from another action on the site and converting it into a file for download.  The url might have additional query string parameters not on the action method parameter list, and I'm looking for a flexible approach, hence the use of a full url.

I've used the `HttpClient` or `WebClient` approach, but they only return the Login page html, and I'm using Forms Authentication.

Is there any other way for one action to retrieve the output of another action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate an object of that controller and call it's action method, but why can't you replace it with a private function or better a service that you can call from any action you want?

Comment: I need to use the actual rendered html, so I need to work with what the view render engine produces, rather than something in the logic/data layer